# Twisted's trap method raises exceptions that don't get caught

Tags: python, twisted

It seems to me as if *failure.trap* method were raising exceptions that cannot be caught with try/except block.

```
from twisted.internet import defer


def someAsynchronousMethod(_):
    print 'I am an asynchronous method and I raise a ZeroDivisionError!!!'
    raise ZeroDivisionError

def __errorHandler(failure):
    print 'I am __errorHandler number 1 !!!!'
    try:
        # Traps only NameError, other Errors will be immediately reraised
        failure.trap(NameError)

        # This code executes only if Exception has been trapped
        ret = {'errno': 666,
               'errmsg': 'NameError'
               }

    # It looks like this code will be executed if Exception has not been trapped
    # instead it was reraised and should be caught here, but it turns out it
    # doesn't get caught, instead the method returns None at this point
    except Exception:
        # This code is never reached
        ret = {'errno': 5000,
               'errmsg': 'OtherError'
               }

    # This code is reached if Exception has been trapped
    return ret

def __successHandler(result):
    print 'Successful execution !!!!'
    return result


def __successHandler2(result):
    print """I expect to receive ret = {'errno': 5000, 'errmsg': 'OtherError'},
          because __errorHandler number 1 is supposed to return a dict !!!!"""
    return result


def __errorHandler2(failure):
    print 'I am __errorHandler number 2 !!!!'
    return failure


d = defer.Deferred()

# Method that raises an Error
d.addCallback(someAsynchronousMethod)

d.addCallbacks(__successHandler, __errorHandler)

d.addCallbacks(__successHandler2, __errorHandler2)

d.callback(0)
```

## OUTPUT:

```
I am an asynchronous method and I raise a ZeroDivisionError!!!
I am __errorHandler number 1 !!!!
I am __errorHandler number 2 !!!!
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twistedFailures.py", line 58, in <module>
    d.callback(0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "twistedFailures.py", line 8, in someAsynchronousMethod
    raise ZeroDivisionError
exceptions.ZeroDivisionError:
```

I expected that whatever Exception is raised by the *failure.trap* method, it will be caught, but I was wrong.

Is there something specific that Twisted does behind the scenes to handle this? If yes, why and what?

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `failure.trap` to re-raise the `ZeroDivisionError` exception. But that only happens in Python 3: in Python 2, `failure.trap` actually re-raises `failure`. The [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.failure.Failure.trap.html) is pretty clear about this:

> In Python 2 the Failure will be raised; in Python 3 the underlying exception will be re-raised.

Twisted's [`Failure`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.failure.Failure.html) class does not inherit from [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) so your `except Exception:` does not catch it. You need `except (Exception, Failure):` instead.